# How can i avoid NaN error at simple form?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got simple form that has to return square root of a number. But i get NaN error. As you can see, variable "number" is number-type. What am i doing wrong?

```js
let number = parseInt(document.getElementById('value'));

function myFunction() {
    alert(Math.sqrt(number));
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        
        <form>
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Number squared</legend>
              <p><label >Insert number here: </label><input type="number" id="value"></p>
            </fieldset>
          <p><input type="button" id="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="calculate"></p>
          </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to get the value of the input.  You're using parseInt on the HTML element...not its **value**

Comment: You try to parse the whole element. Just use `document.getElementById('value').value`.

Comment: First you are accessing the element and trying to make it a number. Second you are doing it once, so you change the value it will not be picked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `document.getElementById()` returns an HTML element. You would have to access the `value` property by doing `document.getElementById().value`. Second, the `number` variable will always be equal to `NaN` since that line of code is executed first and is never changed.

```js
let value = document.getElementById('value').value // Evaluates to ""
let number = parseInt(value); // Evaluates to NaN

// The number variable is never re-evaluated when the function is invoked
function() {
  alert(Math.sqrt(number));
}
```

You would have to move that line of code into your function so that the value of `number` is determined when the function is called, not at the beginning of code execution.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const number = parseInt(document.getElementById('value').value)
  
  if (isNaN(number)) {
    alert('Please pass in a number') 
    return
  }
  
  alert(Math.sqrt(number))
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Number squared</legend>
      <p><label>Insert number here: </label><input type="number" id="value"></p>
    </fieldset>
    <p><input type="button" id="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="calculate"></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
  const number = +document.getElementById('value').value;

  if (isNaN(number)) {
    alert('Please pass in a number') 
    return
  }

  alert(Math.sqrt(number))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `document.getElementById()` returns the element itself and not the value. You need to get the value of the input to parse it as integer.

Change the code to `parseInt(document.getElementById('value').value);`

Answer (score 0):

You must get your element value inside your function call, otherwise you will get NaN(Not a number), like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    let number = parseInt(document.getElementById('value').value);
    if(number !== "" && number != undefined && number != null && !isNaN(number)){
        alert(Math.sqrt(number));
    }else{
        alert("Please enter valid number");
    }
}
```

You can also check for undefined, null and empty string values.